# Grouping a pandas dataframe by months and by hours of these months

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group my dataframe by months and within that month by hours of the day to obtain the mean value of each hour of the day for every month. So far I have run the following line, but it does not work: `df=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'),pd.Grouper(freq='h')]).mean()`. Any idea on how I can do that efficienty?

```
    date  = ['2015-02-03 23:00:00','2015-02-03 23:30:00','2015-02-04 00:00:00','2015-02-04 00:30:00','2015-02-04 01:00:00','2015-02-04 01:30:00','2015-02-04 02:00:00','2015-02-04 02:30:00','2015-02-04 03:00:00','2015-02-04 03:30:00','2015-02-04 04:00:00','2015-02-04 04:30:00','2015-02-04 05:00:00','2015-02-04 05:30:00','2015-02-04 06:00:00','2015-02-04 06:30:00','2015-02-04 07:00:00','2015-02-04 07:30:00','2015-02-04 08:00:00','2015-02-04 08:30:00','2015-02-04 09:00:00','2015-02-04 09:30:00','2015-02-04 10:00:00','2015-02-04 10:30:00','2015-02-04 11:00:00','2015-02-04 11:30:00','2015-02-04 12:00:00','2015-02-04 12:30:00','2015-02-04 13:00:00','2015-02-04 13:30:00','2015-02-04 14:00:00','2015-02-04 14:30:00','2015-02-04 15:00:00','2015-02-04 15:30:00','2015-02-04 16:00:00','2015-02-04 16:30:00','2015-02-04 17:00:00','2015-02-04 17:30:00','2015-02-04 18:00:00','2015-02-04 18:30:00','2015-02-04 19:00:00','2015-02-04 19:30:00','2015-02-04 20:00:00','2015-02-04 20:30:00','2015-02-04 21:00:00','2015-02-04 21:30:00','2015-02-04 22:00:00','2015-02-04 22:30:00','2015-02-04 23:00:00','2015-02-04 23:30:00']
    value = [33.24  , 31.71  , 34.39  , 34.49  , 34.67  , 34.46  , 34.59  , 34.83  , 35.78  , 33.03  , 35.49  , 33.79  , 36.12  , 37.09  , 39.54  , 41.19  , 45.99  , 50.23  , 46.72  , 47.47  , 48.46  , 48.38  , 48.40  , 48.13  , 38.35  , 38.19  , 38.12  , 38.05  , 38.06  , 37.83  , 37.49  , 37.41 , 41.84  , 42.26 , 44.09  , 48.85  , 50.07 , 50.94  , 51.09  , 50.60  , 47.39  , 45.57  , 45.03  , 44.98  , 41.32  , 40.37  , 41.12  , 39.33  , 35.38  , 33.44  ]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'index':date})
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    print(df)    

                         value
    index                     
    2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24
    2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71
    2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39
    2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49
    2015-02-04 01:00:00  34.67
    2015-02-04 01:30:00  34.46
```

Comment: `df.groupby([df.index.month,df.index.hour])['value'].mean()` ?

Comment: So years are not important?

Comment: nice one, I'd recommend choosing the best answer below to close this off :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Dataframe.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html):

```
df2=df.reset_index()    
df3=df2.groupby([df2['index'].dt.year.rename('year'),df2['index'].dt.month.rename('month'),df2['index'].dt.hour.rename('hour')]).mean()
print(df3)
```

---

```
                   value
year month hour         
2015 2     0     34.4400
           1     34.5650
           2     34.7100
           3     34.4050
           4     34.6400
           5     36.6050
           6     40.3650
           7     48.1100
           8     47.0950
           9     48.4200
           10    48.2650
           11    38.2700
           12    38.0850
           13    37.9450
           14    37.4500
           15    42.0500
           16    46.4700
           17    50.5050
           18    50.8450
           19    46.4800
           20    45.0050
           21    40.8450
           22    40.2250
           23    33.4425
​
```

if you do not want to take into account the years simply do not include them when grouping:

```
df3=df2.groupby([df2['index'].dt.month.rename('month'),df2['index'].dt.hour.rename('hour')]).mean()
```

---

```
              value
month hour         
2     0     34.4400
      1     34.5650
      2     34.7100
      3     34.4050
      4     34.6400
      5     36.6050
      6     40.3650
      7     48.1100
      8     47.0950
      9     48.4200
      10    48.2650
      11    38.2700
      12    38.0850
      13    37.9450
      14    37.4500
      15    42.0500
      16    46.4700
      17    50.5050
      18    50.8450
      19    46.4800
      20    45.0050
      21    40.8450
      22    40.2250
      23    33.4425
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is convert all days to `1` and add `hours` for helper `DatetimeIndex` and pass to `groupby`:

```
idx = df.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp() + pd.to_timedelta(df.index.hour, unit='H')
```

Or:

```
idx = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(day=1, minute=0))
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(idx).mean()
print (df)
                       value
index                       
2015-02-01 00:00:00  34.4400
2015-02-01 01:00:00  34.5650
2015-02-01 02:00:00  34.7100
2015-02-01 03:00:00  34.4050
2015-02-01 04:00:00  34.6400
2015-02-01 05:00:00  36.6050
2015-02-01 06:00:00  40.3650
2015-02-01 07:00:00  48.1100
2015-02-01 08:00:00  47.0950
2015-02-01 09:00:00  48.4200
2015-02-01 10:00:00  48.2650
2015-02-01 11:00:00  38.2700
2015-02-01 12:00:00  38.0850
2015-02-01 13:00:00  37.9450
2015-02-01 14:00:00  37.4500
2015-02-01 15:00:00  42.0500
2015-02-01 16:00:00  46.4700
2015-02-01 17:00:00  50.5050
2015-02-01 18:00:00  50.8450
2015-02-01 19:00:00  46.4800
2015-02-01 20:00:00  45.0050
2015-02-01 21:00:00  40.8450
2015-02-01 22:00:00  40.2250
2015-02-01 23:00:00  33.4425
```